# QGIS Plugin with DockWidget and MainWindow

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt, qt

For my QGIS Plugin, that I started with the QGIS Plugin Builder, I built a `QDockWidget` and populated it with some functions.

Now I want to add a `QMainWindow`, since I need more space for further options, but would like to keep my `QDockWidget`, in case that one only needs the "simple" Version of the plugin.

I now have build a simple `QMainWindow` with Qt and want to add it to my plugin. And this is the point where I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You need to explain more your issue, what is your problem? What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same mimic as used in your plugin class that inherits from `QDockWidget`.

If you look into your python code you find something that you can use the same way (provided your QtDesigner file is called `my_main_window.ui`):

```
from PyQt5 import uic
MY_FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'my_main_window.ui'), resource_suffix='')

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, MY_FORM_CLASS):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # from here you can use every designer object by self.<objectname>

    def myFunction(self):
        print('Hello!')
```

Then you can use this with

```
my_win = MyMainWindow()
my_win.show()
```

Sidenote: If you lack some space in your `QDockWidget`, have you been trying some solutions with `QTabWidget`s?

Comment: Hey Jochen, thanks for the help, this way it works! And yes already added some Tabs to my QDockWidget ;)